# Cannot archive properly (Generic archive) for App Store with multiple targets using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, archive

i am creating an iOS app in Swift with Xcode 7 which is being white labeled into two apps with different themes (colors, fonts etc.).
In order to do that I have created two targets, lets call them A and B.

Now I want to archive them so I can upload A and B to iTunes Connect, and I have a scheme for both A and B. When i select one of the schemes, chooses `Generic iOS Device` and archives, it only builds a `Generic Xcode Archive` which I am unable to Upload to App Store.

I am managing my dependencies by CocoaPods and have tried both the 0.39.0 version and the latest 1.0.0.beta.2

I have tried the following changes for the `Build Settings`:
- Changed `Installation Directory` to `/Applications` for both targets
- Have set `Skip Install` to `No` for both targets

What can I do in order to build a proper archive that enables me to upload either the "bundle" containing both A and B to the App Store, or an archive for both A and one for B that I can upload separately?